# Preferable way to use dependencies in build.gradle: compile or compile file?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, build-dependencies

I'm using many external libraries for my project as it saves lot of efforts by reducing the work. I prefer gradle build mechanism.
As Gradle provides following ways for adding dependencies:

1. Use it as external lib (I prefer when library is not available)

   ```
   compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
   ```
2. By adding available jar

   ```
   compile files('libs/picasso-2.5.2.jar')
   ```

What would be the best practice to use libraries in project? What are the pros and cons of using dependencies in above ways?

Comment: Are you manually downloading your jar files? Do they not live in a repository like nexus or artifactory?

Comment: @RaGe most of the time I work offline, so keeping jars on hard drive helps me to keep my work going.

Comment: Well, the way gradle (or even maven) dependency caching works, if you run a gradle build once while you're online, all the dependencies are downloaded and stored in your local cache. Subsequent builds can be offline if you're not changing your dependencies, the required files are fetched from the cache. You can even force offline behavior with the `--offline` flag. In this day and age, I find it very hard to come up with any good reason to use a folder of jars as dependencies especially for standard libs but even for your homegrown ones.

Comment: The last time I used a folder of jars was when I was behind a corp proxy that prevented me from reaching mavenCentral() over https. Even then it was a temporary thing until I figured out how to add the proxy certificate to java truststore.

Answer (score 3):

**Consider:**

- Using any of these solutions does not have any influence on app performance
- It's faster to copy&paste a Gradle line than to copy&paste a file
- It's easier to update Gradle line when new version of the library is released. Just change few digits. You can even set it to update automagically
- When it comes to Android libraries your are informed when there are updates available
- Sometimes you might not have internet access and having a ready .jar file on your hard drive is win in these situations

Myself, I use Gradle whenever I can. It just makes my development process faster and easier.

---

**Update** To make my answer more complete:

- Rémi Pradal had also very interesting insight in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34812326/5199320):

> using compile file [...] will increase a lot the size of your repository as you will probably commit the .jar files.

Comment: Is there any difference in apk sizes when using jar offline or through repository. artifacts? I'm expecting more differences in terms of size and pros and cons!

Comment: There is no difference in size, both methods compile whole library into your apk. If you want to remove unused classes, I suggest using ProGuard. By the way, removing unused code has rather small influence over apk size, removing resources makes bigger impact.

Answer (score 1):

Application performance is not dependent on which method you use for dependency management. Dependency management is for making developer's life easier.

Consider this, new version of a particular library got released with few additional features and you want to migrate to the newer version. If you are using the second method, you will have to remove existing jar file and download new version's jar file and include it in your codebase. But, if you are using the first method, it's just a matter of changing the version.

In conclusion, If the library or jar available in Maven (or any global repository), use the first method. If jar is only available as a direct download, we don't have any other option, go for second method.

Also, for the second option, you can add all jar files to the project in one single line, like this:

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
```